# Can someone explain to me how does this actually work (atoi)

Tags: c

I have written a program that takes 2 arguments from the user and adds them together so for example if the user puts ./test 12 4 it will print out the sum is: 16.

the part that is confusing me is why do I have to use the `atoi` and I can't just use `argv[1] + argv[2]`

I know that `atoi` is used convert a string to an integer and I found this line of code online which helped me with my program but can someone explain to me why do I need it :

```
sum = atoi(argv[1])+atoi(argv[2]);
```

code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main(int argc, char *argv[]) 
{

    int sum = 0;

    sum = atoi(argv[1])+atoi(argv[2]);
    printf("The sum is : %d \n", sum);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: when you say "Strings" in C they are `char*` , ie, pointers to a character array,  when you do argv[1] + argv[2]  you are adding pointers together.

Comment: `argv[1] + argv[2]` means  add two pointers (it will result in an error as an invalid operation) in C.

Comment: The key in what you read is "convert a string to an integer." Without that, you have a string, not a number.  C is not like scripting languages which often try to convert values into the type you need. In C you need to be explicit about what you want.

Comment: `atoi()` capture a `char *` and returns correspond integer. [`atoi()`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/string/byte/atoi)

Comment: Also, there must be some sort of agreement that the strings argv[1] and argv[2] will be digit characters for the decimal representation of an integer of a certain range, whether a leading '+' is allowed, how other bases are represented, if allowed, etc. In other words, arguments are and must be strings, with the interpretation left up the program.

Comment: @KeithNicholas-- strings in C are not `char *`, but null-terminated character arrays; even string literals have type _array of `char`_, i.e., `char []`.

Comment: @David Bowling, the MISRA link you gave doesn't appear to link to a MISRA resource, it's something else instead that looks like good guidance but not MISRA.

Comment: @Zvaii-- note that `atoi()` is considered obsolescent by the [CERT Secure Coding Standard](https://www.securecoding.cert.org/confluence/display/c/MSC24-C.+Do+not+use+deprecated+or+obsolescent+functions), and even [the POSIX Standard](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/atoi.html) suggests obsolescence with: "The `atoi()` function is subsumed by `strtol()` but is retained because it is used extensively in existing code." `atoi()` does no error-checking, and has UB if the number is out of range; `strtol()` does have error-checking. – David Bowling 10 hours ago

Comment: @codeshot-- yes; in my mind I was typing CERT, but in my fingers I was typing MISRA....

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The reason is the same thing as the difference between you and your name. The user typed "./test 12 4" so before your program ran, the command shell that the user is using prepared two sequences of numbers representing the text characters that form the *names* of the user's numbers and gave them to your program - the shell got those directly from the terminal where the user typed them.

In order to add the numbers that these sequences identify by name you need to use a function that converts those two names to `int` - a representation of the numbers that they identify for which addition is defined. This function is called 'atoi' and the two names were the sequences `{49,50,0}` and `{52,0}` (being representations of the symbol sequences `{'1','2','\0'}` and `{'4', '\0'}`). The `0` (also written `'\0'`) is a code for a special symbol that can't be printed or typed directly (this is a lie but I don't want to get into that) and it's added to the end of the names so that `atoi`, as it reads the name character code by character code, knows when it reached the end. Note that these particular values depend on what platform you're using but I'm assuming it's a platform that uses ascii or utf-8 rather than something like ebcdic.

As part of printing the resulting number, `printf` uses the `"%d"` directive to accept the `int` way of representing the answer (which you got from adding two `int`s) and converts it back to to the *name* of the answer as character codes `{49,56}` (`{'1','6'}`) ready to send back to the terminal. I left out any possible terminating `0` (`'\0'`) in the output codes just there because `printf` doesn't indicate an end here unlike the end indications you receive in the inputs from the shell - the terminal can't look for an end in the same way that `atoi` does and `printf` doesn't give you the name for further usage within the C program; it just sends the name right out of the program for display to the terminal (which is the place that the command shell hooked up to the program's output stream).

Although `atoi` isn't the only thing you could do with the incoming names for numbers, the C language has been designed to give the ending marker for each `argv` element because it will typically be needed for any alternative choices you might make for handling the incoming information.

Try this to see the codes being used explicitly (still assuming your system uses ascii or utf-8):

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

char const name_of_program[] = "./test";
char const name_of_first_number[] = {49,50,0}; // {'1','2','\0'} would be the same as would "12" - with the quotes
char const name_of_second_number[] = {52,0}; // {'4','\0'} would be the same as would "4" - with the quotes

int main() 
{
    char const *argv[] = {
        name_of_program,
        name_of_first_number,
        name_of_second_number,
        NULL,
    };
    int sum = 0;

    sum = atoi(argv[1])+atoi(argv[2]);
    printf("The sum is : %d \n", sum);
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Your `argv[i]` is type C string by default:

```
int main(int argc, char *argv[])
```

and sum is type `int`.

Even if you input a number it will be read as a `char*` by your compiler. `atoi()` makes it read as an `int` so you can do arithmetic calculations with it.

[Answer updated thanks to comments bellow]

Comment: A correction: atoi doesn't *cast* the pointer to `int`, it *converts* the start of a C string to an `int`. A cast is defined by the C standard specifically as

"Preceding  an  expression  by  a  parenthesized  type  name  converts  the  value  of  the expression to the named type. This construction is called a cast."

Comment: It's not read as a `char*` either, It's read in as a C string, which is made of a sequence of character codes terminated by a nul character in a single object, a valid beginning point of which is referenced by a `char*` or `char const*`. So there's a lot more to that. It's not just pedantic either, a learner is often misdirected in their understanding when thinking that a pointer is a string and they then go on to make a lot of unnecessary mistakes.

Comment: @codeshot thanks for the reminder. I updated the answer with your comments.

Comment: "`argv[i]` is type `char*`" was correct, since there is no `string` type in C. As you correctly implied in the first version of your answer, `argv[]` is an array of pointers to `char`, and those pointers point to strings (null-terminated character arrays). "It will be read as a `char*`"-- no, command-line arguments are _program parameters_ which are stored as strings; the pointers in `argv[]` point to these strings. "`atoi()` makes it read as an `int`"-- `atoi()` converts a string to an `int` value (without error-checking) if the number is in range, otherwise the behavior is undefined.

Answer (score 0):

"the part that is confusing me is why do i have to use the "atoi" and i can't just use argv[1] + argv[2]"
The argv argument holds a list of strings that the program can take as input. The C language does not automatically convert strings to numbers, so you have to do that yourself. The atoi function takes a string as a parameter and returns an integer, which can then be used for the arithmetic operations you want.
In other languages such as C++, summing strings usually concatenates them, but in C you will get a compiler error.